# Should i close the Mongo connection after some operation?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, redis, database

i would like to understand what is the best practice dealing with database operations.

I always use the mongoose package, but i will change to mongodb package, cause i don't need much, and i would like to know if i should end the connection after some operation or i leave always open??

Also, i'm using redis to queue with node-resque and i have the same doubt. I'm leaving both open, i never close, am i doing something wrong?

Also, i extending the express instance - app - with the queue operation, so i can use in anywhere, is this wrong too?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## MongoDB

It is best practice to open a connection on application initialization and either have the MongoDB driver of choice manage a connection pool (as most drivers do, including the JS driver) or derive new connections from that "master" connection (as it is practice in the Go driver).

The reason why it makes sense to have the driver manage a connection pool is simple: when the number of connections left in the pool drops below a certain threshold, the relative expensive operation of creating a new socket connection to MongoDB and maybe even authenticating is done in background. So when new connections are requested by the application, they do not need to be created.

## Redis

I don't know much about Redis, but for a pub-sub scenario, you obviously should maintain the connection to get updates asap.

Answer (score 0):

The standard best practice for MongoDB is to keep the connection open at all times. This is stated [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/node-mongodb-native/mSGnnuG8C1o/Hiaqvdu1bWoJ) by MongoDB nodejs driver main developer.